# Fibonacci number algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

How to explain that the number of `1`s in the string printed by the below function, `FibonacciRecursion(n)`, is equal to the `n`-th Fibonacci number?

```
public static void FibonacciRecursion(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1) 
    {
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    else
    {
        FibonacciRecursion(n-1);
        FibonacciRecursion(n-2);
    }
}
```

For example, `FibonacciRecursion(6)` prints `1011010110110` and the `6`-th Fibonacci number is `8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by induction. Let `ONES(x)` be the number of `1`s in the binary string `x`.  The outputs of `F(0)` and `F(1)` satisfy the property you mentioned, i.e., `ONES(F(0)) = FIB(0)` and `ONES(F(1)) = FIB(1)`.

Now, if you assume that for all `m<=n`, `n>=1`, `ONES(F(m)) = FIB(m)` then

```
ONES(F(n+1)) = ONES(F(n) concat F(n-1))
             = ONES(F(n)) + ONES(F(n-1))
             = FIB(n) + FIB(n-1)
             = FIB(n+1),
```

completing the induction.